# Creating multiple objects from SQL server extract

Tags: c#, object-oriented, sql-server

I've created a simplified prototype solution as a sort of proof of concept before starting a larger program.

Here is the test data used to build the objects:

```sql
create table blah.dbo.tb_sandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects
(
    CustomerName varchar(50),
    ItemCode varchar(50)
);

insert into blah.dbo.tb_sandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects
values 
    ('jq','bat'),
    ('jq','blackRubber'),
    ('jq','redRubber'),
    ('mt','redRubberX'),
    ('mt','redRubberY'),
    ('mt','redRubberZ'),
    ('mt','blackRubberA'),
    ('mt','blackRubberB'),
    ('mt','bladeFast'),
    ('mt','bladeVeryFast'),
    ('mt','bladeTooFast');
```

It has two concrete classes representing customers and items that the customers have bought. There are a few customers but potentially many items.

The only use case I have to address is:

An administrator identifies a user, then the system will display the items bought by that user. The system does not need to send any information back to SQL server.

Here are the two concrete classes:

class: **Customer**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects
{
  class Customer
  {

    //links
    List<Item> items;
    Item i;

    //property
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    //constructor
    public Customer(String name)
    {
      items = new List<Item>();
      Name = name;
    }

    //method to add link to item bought by customer
    public void addItem(Item i)
    {
      items.Add(i);
    }

  }
}
```

class: **Item**

```
using System;

namespace SandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects
{
  class Item
  {

    //name property
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public Item(String name)
    {
      this.Name = name;
    }

  }
}
```

I have an orchestrating/coordinating class that ultimately will talk to the user interface:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;



namespace SandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects
{
  class AppCoordinator
  {

    Dictionary<String,Customer> customers;

    private string connString;
    private const string targetTableName = @"blah.dbo.tb_sandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects";
    private DataTable dt;


    public AppCoordinator()
    {
      //this will contain links to the customers
      customers = new Dictionary<string,Customer>();

      //fill the main datatable
      this.dt = fillDataTable();

      //get a distinct view of the customers
      //instantiate the customer objects
      DataView view = new DataView(dt);
      DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true,new String[] { "CustomerName" });
      foreach(DataRow row in distinctValues.Rows)
      {
        String custName = row["CustomerName"].ToString();
        customers.Add(custName,new Customer(custName));
      }

      //then the instantiate the item objects
      foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
        String custName = row["CustomerName"].ToString();
        Customer linkedCustomer;
        customers.TryGetValue(custName,out linkedCustomer);
        String itemName = row["ItemCode"].ToString();
        Item i = new Item(itemName);
        linkedCustomer.addItem(i);
      }

    }


    //gets data from the server
    private DataTable fillDataTable()
    {
      this.connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString;

      SqlConnection conn = null;
      SqlDataAdapter ad = null;
      DataSet ds = null;
      DataTable returnDt = null;
      try
      {
        conn = new SqlConnection(this.connString);
        ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + targetTableName,conn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds,"AvailableReports");
        returnDt = ds.Tables["AvailableReports"];
      }
      catch(SqlException ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      }
      finally
      {
        if(conn != null)
        {
          conn.Close();
          conn.Dispose();
        }
      }

      return returnDt;
    }

    //a read-only copy of the dictionary
    //read-only for hiding purposes
    public ReadOnlyDictionary<String,Customer> getCustomers()
    {
      return new ReadOnlyDictionary<String,Customer>(customers);
    }

  }
}
```

Here is `Main` which resides in `Program`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace SandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects
{
  class Program
  {

    private AppCoordinator appCoord;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      Program p = new Program();
      p.appCoord = new AppCoordinator();



      ReadOnlyDictionary<String,Customer> dics = p.appCoord.getCustomers();
      Console.WriteLine("{0}",dics.Count);
      foreach(String aName in dics.Keys)
      {
        Customer c;
        dics.TryGetValue(aName,out c);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has this many items: {1}",c.Name, c.getItems().Count);
      }

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
      Console.Read();
    }
  }
}
```

It works ok. I am new to OOP so any tips and pointers on this code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Customer and Item classes

Well, to start with, `Customer.i` isn't used and I don't see how it could ever be. So that should just go away.

Your naming style is off for C#; you should be using PascalCase instead of camelCase for public methods (eg., AddItem).

`Customer.AddItem` and `Customer.GetItems` don't add much value; they're OK as-is, and are actually a reasonable encapsulation - but they're kind of overkill here. (as an aside, your `Customer` class doesn't include `GetItems`, but I inferred it from your `Main`). 
This comment could really be directed to the whole structure, actually - since you really just need a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to solve the problem. Not to say the structure can't be useful, but I would consider it overkill unless there's some future plans being made here.

### Program class

Your `Program` class sets a private `AppCoordinator` member, but never uses it outside of `Main`; it's odd to have a class instantiate itself like this. In this case, you can just use the `AppCoordinator` as a local.

`Console.WriteLine` will take an object and call `.ToString` on it for you; no reason to use the format overload.

```
  Console.WriteLine(dics.Count);
```

You can `foreach` over the `Dictionary` directly, getting a `KeyValuePair<string, Customer>`. Or you can `foreach` over `Dictionary.Values` and just get the `Customer`. Either would be preferable to going over the `Keys` just to get to the `Value` (and you don't check the return of `TryGetValue`). 
I'd also change the name of your `dics` variable since the trailing `s` implies that it's multiple dictionaries (FWIW, I'd probably go with just `d` just so I didn't have to ever read a potentially offensive word over the phone; but that's just me!)

```
  foreach(Customer customer in dic.Values)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} has this many items: {1}", customer.Name, customer.GetItems().Count);
  }
```

`Console.Read` will exit at any key; you want to change your message or change that to `Console.ReadLine` to require an `Enter`.

### AppCoordinator

Your `AppCoordinator` class is a major code smell; it's a (no offense) terrible name that really doesn't describe what it's doing, and is likely to become a "god object". I would rename that to `CustomerRepository` or `CustomerDataAccess` or something.

Since this is your largest class, the meat of my comments are here:

- prefer smallest scope possible for variables: `targetTableName` and `dt` should all be locals; technically so should `connString`, but we'd generally want the ability to set that one from a constructor or something
- don't do work you don't have to: `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` will fill just a `DataTable`, don't pass it a `DataSet` just to pull out the `DataTable`
- prefer `using` over explicit `Dispose`: it reads better, and is much easier to get correct
- Some will quibble, but I don't like the assignment to a local just to return at the end
- Don't catch exceptions that you can't do anything about; if you do want to log, then `throw` at the end (otherwise, you just returned an empty datatable which someone is going to read and think there's been no sales)
- Pet peeve, but I prefer explicit cast to calling `ToString`; that makes you explicitly deal with `DbNull`
- You generally don't want to be doing data access or other "real" work in the constructor; it opens you up to possible exceptions, makes inheritance harder, and is generally unexpected. Move all of that to the `GetCustomers` method.
  I'm not sure that it's a requirement, but your existing code does end up caching the database results; you can do that lazily instead.
- Maybe not now, but you'll definitely want to consider finding a mini (or full) ORM to cut out the repetitive ADO.NET code.
- Using `DataTables` isn't the end of the world, but not really standard at this point. I'd switch those to a `DataReader` instead since you don't really need the extra functiuonality of the `DataTable`.
  You do use it to build a distinct `Customer` list, but that can be done with a `ContainsKey` on your `Dictionary` instead.

So, I'd suggest it'd end up looking something like (it's been awhile since I've written straight ADO.NET, so there may be some minor issues here):

```
 class CustomerDataAccess 
 {
     private string readonly connectionString;
     private ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Customer> readOnlyCustomers;

     public CustomerDataAccess() 
        : this(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString)
     {
     }
     public CustomerDataAccess(string connectionString)
     {
         this.connectionString = connectionString;
     }

     public ReadOnlyDictionary<String,Customer> GetCustomers()
     {
         if (this.readOnlyCustomers == null) 
         {
            Dictionary<String, Customer> customers = this.GetCustomersInternal();
            this.readOnlyCustomers = new ReadOnlyDictionary(customers);
         }

         return this.readOnlyCustomers;
     }

     private Dictionary<String, Customer> GetCustomersInternal()
     {
         const string targetTableName = @"blah.dbo.tb_sandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects";
         try 
         {
             using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + targetTableName, conn))
             {
                 conn.Open();

                 Dictionary<string,Customer> customers = new Dictionary<string,Customer>();
                 using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     string customerName = dr.GetString("CustomerName");
                     Customer customer;
                     if (!customers.TryGetValue(customerName, out customer))
                     {
                         customer = new Customer(customerName);
                         customers.Add(customer.Name, customer);
                     }

                     string itemCode = dr.GetString("ItemCode");
                     Item item = new Item(itemCode);
                     customer.AddItem(item);
                 }

                 this.readOnlyCustomers = new ReadOnlyDictionary(customers);
             }
         }
         catch (SqlException ex)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hello Mark. I've refactored with most of your suggestions (not all). Should I re-post the new version in a further question? There maybe aspects of your suggestions that I've not implemented that you feel are more important than some which I have taken on board.

Answer (score 1):

Please have **explicit access modifiers**. I do not want to figure out whether `class Customer` and `List<Item> items;` and `class Item` etc. are `public` or `internal` or `private`.

---

**Comments** should say **why** something was implemented that way. `//name property` doesn't tell me anything I can't see with my own eyes.

---

[**Use the aliases** whenever possible](http://peterkellner.net/2007/12/29/incsharpwhentousestringversesstring/): `string` instead of `String`, `int` instead of `Int32`,...

---

What kind of namespace is `SandpitCreateMultipleLinkedObjects`? Most of that seems to be a method name. Look at `System.Data.SqlClient` or `System.Collections.Generic` etc. for examples of proper namespaces. I know you said that this is a "a sort of proof of concept", but that still doesn't mean you should abandon **good naming practices**.

Even the code I write for applications only I will ever use is as close to "professional" code as possible for two good reasons:

- It helps create good habits.
- Plenty of times I find I reuse such "quick fix" applications over a long period and I need to maintain them; having decent code is just easy to work with.

---

All of that db code in `AppCoordinator` should really move to a separate **layer**. You should have one class that just converts db data to objects (`Customer`, etc.), and other classes should consume it.

---

You should look at [**database normalization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Your current db structure looks simple, but in reality it obscuring a far more complicated one. Hence the rather forced way you first create `Customer`s and then create `Item`s that are linked to that `Customer`. You loop through the same `DataTable` twice in doing so, which should be a warning sign.

---

`SqlConnection` etc. should be [encapsulated in a **`using`** statement](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection).

Comment: (upped) appreciated the pointers. I aim to write professional standard code even when writing prototype code inside a sandpit but I am still learning ...hence my post. Tomorrow I will refactor and put in place your suggestions. I assume you are saying the db code should be in a class that is then used, via composition, inside the coordinator class?

Comment: @whytheq Ideally you should work with interfaces and use IoC/dependency injection to link the various layers. Also remember the single responsibility principle from SOLID when it comes to classes and methods.